# Add AD Security group as Site collection administrator - SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is there a way to add a security group as Primary or secondary site collection administrator to all the sites in the tenant via PowerShell?

I know this works for adding a **user account** to all the sites as SC Admin

```
$Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL
Foreach ($Site in $Sites)
{
Set-SPOUser -site $Site.Url -LoginName $AdminName -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
```

The same command with `Set-SPOSiteGroup`  does not work

```
Set-SPOSiteGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IsSiteCollectionAdmin'
```

Since 'IsSiteCollectionAdmin' is not accepted with `Set-SPOSiteGroup`

Any suggestions on how to set security group as site collection administrator via  PS script/ cmdlets?

Answer (score 2):

Just tried it here and worked for me. I'm using [PNP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) and assuming you got the Security group ID from Azure AD. Microsoft documentation also states:

"You must be a Site Collection Admin to run...[the Add-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin] ...command. Use Set-PnPTenantSite -Owners if you are not an Admin for the site but have the SharePoint admin role."

```
Connect-PNPOnline "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollection"
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$admins = Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin
write-host "Original Site Colletion Admins: " $admins
$azureADGroup = "c:0t.c|tenant|AzureAD-SecurityGroup-ID"
$ensureUser = $web.EnsureUser($azureADGroup)
$user = Get-PnPUser -Identity $azureADGroup
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -Owners $user.LoginName
```

Comment: Thank you it did work  - - 
>

Similar solution - 
https://kirkbarrett.wordpress.com/2016/04/04/adding-an-o365-security-group-to-the-site-collection-administrators-group/

Answer (score 0):

You can not add AD security group as Site Collection administrator.

Refer [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/149a31b5-3e4d-4aba-a2ad-b4b4d5b6bd14/active-directory-group-as-site-collection-administrator-is-it-possible?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) link.

Comment: This seems to be really outdated and definitely not for SharePoint Online.